# Custom Forget Password page

Tags: page-template, password

I am trying to create a custom Reset password page. I got this code from a tutorial:

```
<?php  
/* 
Template Name: Reset Page
*/

get_header()
?>
<div class="wrapper">

    <?php
        global $wpdb;

        $error = '';
        $success = '';

        // check if we're in reset form
        if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && 'reset' == $_POST['action'] ) 
        {
            $email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email']));

            if( empty( $email ) ) {
                $error = 'Enter a username or e-mail address..';
            } else if( ! is_email( $email )) {
                $error = 'Invalid username or e-mail address.';
            } else if( ! email_exists( $email ) ) {
                $error = 'There is no user registered with that email address.';
            } else {

                $random_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
                $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );

                $update_user = wp_update_user( array (
                        'ID' => $user->ID, 
                        'user_pass' => $random_password
                    )
                );

                // if  update user return true then lets send user an email containing the new password
                if( $update_user ) {
                    $to = $email;
                    $subject = 'Your new password';
                    $sender = get_option('name');

                    $message = 'Your new password is: '.$random_password;

                    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
                    $headers[] = 'From: '.$sender.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";

                    $mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
                    if( $mail )
                        $success = 'Check your email address for you new password.';

                } else {
                    $error = 'Oops something went wrong updaing your account.';
                }

            }

            if( ! empty( $error ) )
                echo '<div class="message"><p class="error"><strong>ERROR:</strong> '. $error .'</p></div>';

            if( ! empty( $success ) )
                echo '<div class="error_login"><p class="success">'. $success .'</p></div>';
        }
    ?>

    <!--html code-->
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <p>Please enter your username or email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email.</p>
            <p><label for="user_login">Username or E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login"  value="" /></p>
            <p>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
                <input type="submit" value="Get New Password" class="button" id="submit" />
            </p>
        </fieldset> 
    </form>
</div>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

### Log:

Upon submitting my username or email address I am getting an Error and a warning:

```
=> Error: wpdb::escape is deprecated since version 3.6! Use wpdb::prepare() or esc_sql() instead.

-- Debug: Undefined index: email on line 41 of C:\xampp2\htdocs\nbmwp\wp-content\themes\mytheme\page-forgotpass.php
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Source:** http://www.sutanaryan.com/how-to-create-custom-reset-or-forget-password-in-wordpress/

Comment: Any `<input name="email" />` exists within your document? Or you have different name than your email

Comment: Good lord... how did I miss that... after changing name="user_login" its working fine... Thanks. There's a security issue with the form though there should be a nonce checking...